# Rails --> an n+1 database issue that won't go away

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to optimise some N+1 queries in active record for the first time. There are 3 to kill - 2 went very easily with a .includes call, but I can't for the life of me figure out why the third is still calling a bunch of queries. Relevant code below - if anyone has any suggestions, I'd be really appreciative.

CONTROLLER:

```
@enquiries = Comment.includes(:children).faqs_for_project(@project)
```

MODEL;

```
def self.faqs_for_project(project)
  Comment.for_project_and_enquiries(project, project.enquiries).where(:published => true).order("created_at DESC")
end
```

(and the relevant scope)

```
scope :for_project_and_enquiries, lambda{|p, qs| where('(commentable_type = ? and commentable_id = ?) or (commentable_type = ? and commentable_id IN (?))', "Project", p.id, "Enquiry", qs.collect{|q| q.id})}
```

VIEW:

```
...
= render :partial => 'comments/comment', :collection => @enquries
...
```

(and that offending line in the partial)

```
...
= 'Read by ' + pluralize(comment.acknowledgers.count, 'lead')
...
```

Two SQL queries are called for each comment. The 2 queries are:

```
SQL (2.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "acknowledgements" ON "users".id = "acknowledgements".user_id WHERE (("acknowledgements".feedback_type = 'Comment') AND ("acknowledgements".feedback_id = 177621))
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1295 LIMIT 1
```

I would have thought appending (:user, :acknowledgements) into the controller's .includes would have solved the problem, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. If anyone has any suggestions on what I'm missing, I'd be really appreciative

Comment: Why you do include if you are calling a class method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe in your `Comment` table you want to add a `:acknowledgers_count` column as a counter cache

```
has_many :acknowledgers, ....., counter_cache: true
```

You will need to create a migration to add the `:acknowledgers_count` column to the `comments` table. Rails should take care of the rest.

You can learn more about the `ActiveRecord::CounterCache` api **[here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache.html)**.

The `count` method in `comment.acknowledgers.count` is overloaded in ActiveRecord to first check if a counter cache column exists, and if it does, it returns that directly from the model *(in this case the `Comment` model)* without having to touch the database again.

Finally, there was very recently a great [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/372-bullet) about a gem call [Bullet](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) that can help you identify these query issues and guide you toward a solution. It covers both counter caches and N+1 queries.

As @ismaelga pointed out in a comment to this answer, it's a generally better practice to call `.size` instead of `.count` on a relation. Check out [the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L196) for `size`:

```
def size
  loaded? ? @records.length : count
end
```

If the relation is already loaded it will just call `length` on it, otherwise it will call `count`. It's an extra check to try and prevent the database from unnecessarily being queried.

Comment: and call size instead of count

Comment: Fantastic - many thanks. (Interestingly, switching to .size made the :acknowledgers .includes work...which makes sense now; my bad)